# How to change the status of order from pending to payment done by credit card?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento when I create an order using credit card payment type after completing the order it will display me order status to `pending`. Instead of this I want `Payment through Credit card` status or something like `Credit card Payment` so that admin is aware that the payment is completed.

Actually I want to add new status if possible for the orders done using credit cards, so it's easy for admin to filter it.

[image: Snapshot of credit card screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"New order status" options is what you need to set for orders made by CC payment method. Depending on your Magento version there are 2 ways of adding new order statuses:

#### Magento CE 1.6+ (EE 1.10+)

This is very simple. Go to `Admin Panel > System > Order statuses` and create a new one there. Then click on 'Assign Status to State'. From statuses list select new created status and from states list select 'New'. It has to be state 'New', otherwise it won't be listed at payment method's config.

Here's step by step of adding new order status:

1. Go to Admin Panel > System > Order Statuses. You will see a grid of all statuses defined so far.
2. Click on 'Create New Status' button
3. You will see new status edit page. You must fill 'Status Code' and 'Status Label', because they're mandatory. Your status code can be e.g. 'cc_payment' and status label e.g. 'Credit Card Payment'. Other fields you can omit, since they are just other language labels.
4. Click on 'Save Status' button. You will be redirected back to the order statuses grid. You should see your new status on the list.
5. Click on 'Assign Status to State' button (next to the 'Create New Status').
6. From 'Order Status' drop-down list select your new status ('Credit Card Payment'). From 'Order State' drop-down list select 'New'.
7. Click on 'Save Status Assignment' button.
8. Go to payment method configuration (System > Configuration > Payment Methods) and set this new order status were desired.

#### Magento CE 1.5 (EE 1.8) and lower

Managind order statuses and states was done by config.xml. So, in order to add a new status, you would like to create a new module (e.g. `Company_Sales`) and in config.xml put a similar xml structure to this one:

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <order>
            <statuses>
                <cc_payment translate="label"><label>Credit card Payment</label></cc_payment>
            </statuses>
            <states>
                <new>
                    <statuses>
                        <cc_payment default="0"/>
                    </statuses>
                </new>
            </states>
        </order>
    </sales>
</global>
```

Comment: Will you please provide me the steps how to add new status for credit card from admin as you mention here in first method. i am having magento 1.7.0.2 in my server and i would like to add new status

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have there step by step of adding new order status.

Comment: Thank Ventus for you kind response I hope that i will get the same response every time from you! and i will always be waiting for your response. thnx.